# Three different tick marks in a graph

Tags: python, graph

I want to have three `tickmarks` of different length in a graph, but I can't find any way or library to be able to set more than two tick marks. I tried to play with major, and minor locators with `matplotlib`, but it did not work, I need something like a medium locator.

Here is an example of what I'm looking for:

Tick marks:

[image: Tick marks]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Matplotlib is open source, just implement your own based on it.